# Angular 5 CLI Production issue

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I just installed the latest version of Angular CLI (1.5.0) and created a brandnew Angular 5 project with "ng new testproject".
I can run the project without problems.
But then I built it:

> ng build --target=production --environment=prod -aot false --base-href
>   "/testproject/"

This works without problems. But when I try to execute the result, I get an angular error, I do not understand:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'e' imported by the module 'e'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at c (main.cc62ca12538e9fa026de.bundle.js:1)
    at main.cc62ca12538e9fa026de.bundle.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e.getNgModuleMetadata (main.cc62ca12538e9fa026de.bundle.js:1)
    at e._loadModules (main.cc62ca12538e9fa026de.bundle.js:1)
    at e._compileModuleAndComponents (main.cc62ca12538e9fa026de.bundle.js:1)
    at e.compileModuleAsync (main.cc62ca12538e9fa026de.bundle.js:1)
    at e.compileModuleAsync (main.cc62ca12538e9fa026de.bundle.js:1)
    at e.LMZF.e.bootstrapModule (main.cc62ca12538e9fa026de.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.cDNt (main.cc62ca12538e9fa026de.bundle.js:1)
```

I have absolutely no idea, where the problem might be. I did not change a single line of code in the project. It's just what the CLI generated.
If I just "npm start" my new project it works. But the built version does not.

Any proposals?

Comment: do you have any dependencies in your project, do you use any libs?

Comment: --aot not -aot?

Comment: you are likely missing some modules. if you're debugging in chrome go to sources and pause on exceptions and see what module is missing